# Accessing method button from masterpage and use onclick event on child

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, controls, sql-delete

## Problem 1

I'm trying to use an Onclick event from a search button, that is located on the master page, in a child page. I found a good solution on this site but it doesn't work.

Link to it:
[How to handle master page button event in content page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687134/how-to-handle-master-page-button-event-in-content-page)

The difference with that solution is that my IpageInterface is located in the App_Code folder and is in the namespace Business.

Other then that it's pretty much the same.

So I have the IpageInterface class:

```
namespace Business {
    public interface IpageInterface {
        void DoSomeAction();
    }
}
```

Then on my master page I have:

```
using Business;

public partial class site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage {
    protected void SearchQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        IpageInterface pageInterface = Page as IpageInterface;
        if (pageInterface != null) {
            pageInterface.DoSomeAction();
        }
    }            
}
```

And finally I have, on the page I want to use it (results page, because the button is a search button):

```
using Business;

public partial class results : System.Web.UI.Page, IpageInterface {
public void DoSomeAction() {
    ContentPlaceHolder mainContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("mainContent");

    if (mainContent != null) {
        DropDownList ddlSearchOn = (DropDownList)mainContent.FindControl("ddlSearchOn");
        TextBox TxtSearch = (TextBox)mainContent.FindControl("TxtSearch");

        if (ddlSearchOn.Text == "Everything" || ddlSearchOn.Text == "Title" || ddlSearchOn.Text == "Text") {
            List<News> newsSearchResults = News.SearchNews(ddlSearchOn.Text, TxtSearch.Text);

            foreach(News newsArticle in newsSearchResults) {
                newsArticle.Text = LimitCharacters(newsArticle.Text, 350);
            }

            repeaterSearchResults.DataSource = newsSearchResults;
            repeaterSearchResults.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I press the button, and I look at the value of pageInterface it says it's null.

## Problem 2

**EDIT:**
Problem 2 is solved. I selected 'Cascade' next to the delete rule in Foreign Key relationships window.

Besides that problem I have a second problem with MS SQL which goes as follows:
I have news articles with comments, when I want to remove the article I have to remove the comments as well, so I use the following query:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"DELETE FROM News_comments WHERE News_comments.news_Id = @news_Id AND News_comments.account_Id = @account_Id;
                                              DELETE FROM News_news WHERE News_news.news_Id = @news_Id"
                                              , conn);
```

The problem is though, that it still seems to thing that the article still has comments, eventhough the comments are removed. So I can't remove the article.
The exception is:

```
"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint" exception.
```

Would appreciate the needed help!

Comment: You don't have to do the double delete if you set up your foreign key in the comments table to do *cascade delete* when the associated row in the source table (articles) is deleted.

Comment: Nevermind, I'll just give the needed info to the child page through the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really a solution to the problem I had with the code above but it is a solution to my situation.

I just give the needed info to the child page through the url. It's not personal or restricted data so it's not a problem.